# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldcmimage

Tags: linux, makefile, dicom, dcmtk

Am trying to compile dcmbeam using make on Centos 7 -x64, however I am getting these errors:

```
    make
    c++ -g -O -I/usr/include/libxml2 -D_REENTRANT -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_BSD_COMPAT -D_OSF_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L -Wall  -L/usr/local/dicom/lib -o dcmbeam dcmbeam.o -ldcmimage -ldcmimgle -ldcmdata -lofstd -lz  -lpthread
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldcmimage
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldcmimgle
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldcmdata
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lofstd

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [dcmbeam] Error 1
```

any ideas what its trying to find? and what location it is looking at?
I will attach the src code zipped on dropbox, link:
[Download Src code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yk2v5ywdmo8tj9x/dicom.zip?dl=0)

thanks alot!

Comment: That's complaining that it cannot find the `dcmimage`, `dcmimgle`, `dcmdata` and `ofstd` libraries for linking. Is that a command `make` is running that failed? Do you have those libraries (and headers) installed?

Comment: I solved the problems by editing the Makefile and pointing LIBDIRS to the libraries and I then recompiled and faced another errors.

Comment: Yes Etan only: make             Here are the errors: http://pastebin.com/KeLaT0eX

Comment: Something is still missing or the version is wrong. I'm not sure. I would go talk to whoever is responsible for dcmbeam/etc.

Comment: I also think the version is wrong and I must get back to the older version of dcmtk and compile it.

Answer (score 1):

Being one of the DCMTK developers, I looked at your error log and it seems that you forgot to link the "oflog" library (which has been introduced with [DCMTK 3.6.0](http://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?t=2787)).